# What is the difference between "kio" and "kiu"?

Tags: word-usage

I am a beginner and I can't understand the difference between "kio" and "kiu". The explanations that I have read so far only leaves me confused and to me it seems that "kio" and "kiu" are sometimes interchangeable.

Answer (score 13):

### **kio** = **what**

Examples:

> *Kio* estas tio? → *What* is that? (Is it a dog? Is it a cat?)
>
> *Kion* vi deziras? → *What* do you want? (A pen? An ice-cream?)

---

### **kiu** = **which** [one of a group, type, etc.] or **who**

Examples:

> *Kiu* estas via aŭto? → *Which* is your car? (Which one of all these cars is yours? That one over there? Or this one here?)
>
> *Kiun* vi deziras? → *Which* do you want? (Which thing of all these things do you want? The pen? Or maybe the ice-cream?)
>
> *Kiu* manĝis mian glaciaĵon? → *Who* ate my ice-cream? (To match the meaning of “which” you can think of *who* meaning *which one of the people*.)

---

Compare *Kion vi volas?* and *Kiun vi volas?* above to see the difference directly.

Comment: A slight detail - "voli" is for verbs, and "deziri" is for nouns. You might want to use "kion vi deziras" instead.

Comment: @ClaytonRamsey "voli" is actually very commonly used with nouns, and "deziri" can be used with verbs; ReVo says the difference between "voli" and "deziri" is that "voli" often implies an intention of acting to realize the desire.

Answer (score 12):

They are definitely not interchangable.

Trying to literally translate them to English you would end up in

> kio = what
>
> kiu = which

A rule that I find quite useful is

*If it stands with a nounish word, it's "kiu", if it stands independently it's "kio".*

Example:

> **Kio** estas en la skatolo kaj **kio** estas sur la tablo?
>
> En la skatolo estas skribiloj kaj sur la tablo estas unu skribilo.

As opposed to

> **Kiuj** *skribiloj* estas en la skatolo kaj **kiu** *skribilo* estas sur la tablo?

In the first example "kio" stands indipendently and in the second example it stands together with the noun "skribilo(j)". According to the form of the noun, "kiu" also takes the plural and accusative markers.

What is sometimes confusing is, that you'd drop the noun that stands with "kiu". For example again the above dialog

> **Kio** estas en la skatolo kaj **kio** estas sur la tablo?
>
> En la skatolo estas skribiloj kaj sur la tablo estas unu skribilo.
>
> **Kiuj** estas en la skatolo kaj **kiu** estas sur la tablo?

The answer to the first question made it clear, that we are talking about several pens in the box and one pen on the table. So in the followup question we can drop the noun, because we can assume it out of the context.

So in order to "kiu" to be able to stand alone there has to be a clear context, which noun it is refering to. If there's no such context it is usually assumed that one is talking about a person.

> **Kio** alvenis? (What has just arrived)
>
> Aŭto.
>
> **Kiu** sidas en la aŭto? (**Who** is sitting in the car?)
>
> Mia patro kaj lia hundo.

If you ask

> **Kio** sidas en la aŭto?

a possible answer would be

> Persono kaj hundo.
>
> **Kiu** hundo sidas en la aŭto? (Which dog ...)
>
> Tiu de mia patro. (My father's one)

The corresponding -io and -iu words behave similarly.

Answer (score 6):

*Tiu* goes with a noun, *tiu homo*: *that person*, for example; *tio* does not. The slightly complicated thing is that for *tiu* the noun might be implied, so, gesturing at a room of people including someone standing on their head: *rigardu tiun* is correct, since the *homo* in *rigardu tiun homon* is understood, but gesturing at an explosion *rigardu tion* is correct.

Once *tiu* and *tio* make sense, *kiu* and *kio* follow; *kiu* is *which one*, so it asks which among a collection of objects is meant, whereas *kio* means *what*.